# How to write multiple conditions(either 1 or 2) on left side of conditions in Drools rule(DSL)

Tags: pentaho, drools, dsl, pentaho-data-integration

I am new to Drools and I am writing rules to expose my business logic as per requirement. I need to write one rule which accepts both field and value to compare.

Input: Data grid/database result rest/Excel sheet with multiple fields with numeric values

**Example**

> {field} > {Staic value}
>   **or**
>   {field1} >{field2}

I can write two rules as follows to achieve this but my intention is to write single rule to match this both the criterias.

[condition][row]  {field1} greater than {field2}

[condition][row]  {field1} greater than "{static_value}".

**Objective:** write single rule in DSL which parses either field/column from input or static value provided .

Can you please help me on achieving this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a simple basic example: 5 row of input data, 2 rules, the expected Excel result.

Answer (score 0):

You have a [Rule Executor](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Rule+Executor) which check a set of drools rules for each row, and a [Rule Accumulator](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Rule+Accumulator) which checks a set of drools rule on a whole data set.

The rules may be coded in the steps or imported from an external file.

So you use the Input Table step to read the data in, pass it to the `Rule executor/accumulator`, then give the result to the `Excel Writer`.

Comment: Hi Alain,Thanks for reply but my expectation here  is to know how to write single rule in DSL which can be applied to both the conditions mentioned below so that rule executor will execute those rules based on the data sets configured in Data grid/table data.

1) compare values from two fields in the grid 
2) compare the field to the static value

Comment: Do you need drools ? And please, give a working example, so that we can avoid giving good answers to the wrong question.